# How to use forEach to check if there is a match in the array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

How to use forEach to check if there is a match in the array (JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking; how do you "log out" variables in code?

In general, you don't need a loop to check existence an array; that's what the [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method is for:

```
if (files.includes(upload.type)) {
    console.log("type is OK")
} else {
    console.log(`type ${upload.type} not found`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

const isMatch = files.some((type) => upload.type === type);